# Null values ​are seen as strings in a SQL insert using Python and SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm encountering a slightly weirder problem when I try to insert a query using SqlAlchemy.
For example, when I have no values, I set None for the value in the query

```
if pandas.isnull(row[client_column]):
   row[client_column] = None
```

My query looks like this

```
 INSERT INTO public.products (PRODUCT_URL) VALUES('NULL')
```

And the problem I am facing is the following

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: ...of 1 In the Box One Pair Of Shoes', 'AW Bellies', 'None', 'T...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Token "None" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: None
```

I also set "null" and "NULL" but it says string after in db

Comment: NULL is not a valid JSON object, maybe try "{}" as an empty JSON?

Comment: Yes, but then it will be put in my database {} not null

Comment: Is this column in database nullable or not?